# Currency Converter - Need Assistance

Tags: java, jframe, converters, currency, valueconverter

I am having a hard time finding the source of the problem in my currency converter.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Adam_Markros_Valutaomvandlare extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel left, middle, right;
    JFrame ram;
    JButton buttonOK;
    JTextField fieldfrom, fieldto, extrafield;
    JLabel labelfrom, labelto, labeldollar, labeleuro, labelpund, labelkrona, extralabel, nothing;
    JRadioButton buttonDollar, buttonEuro, buttonPund, buttonKrona;
    JRadioButton buttonDollar2, buttonEuro2, buttonPund2, buttonKrona2;
    ButtonGroup GroupFrom = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup GroupTo = new ButtonGroup();

    int currencyFrom;
    int currencyTo;
    int taljare = 0;
    int USD     = 6;
    int Pund = 10;
    int Euro = 9;
    int other;
    int namnare = 0;

    public Adam_Markros_Valutaomvandlare(){
        left = new JPanel();
        middle = new JPanel();
        right = new JPanel();

        setSize(600,250);
        setTitle("Adam Markros - Valutaomvandlare");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        left.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));
        middle.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));
        right.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));

        this.add(left);
        this.add(middle);
        this.add(right);

        buttonOK = new JButton("OK");
        fieldfrom = new JTextField();
        fieldto = new JTextField();
        extrafield = new JTextField();
        labelfrom = new JLabel("Från:");
        labelto = new JLabel("Till:");
        extralabel = new JLabel("Annan valuta:");
        nothing = new JLabel("");

        buttonDollar = new JRadioButton("USD");
        buttonEuro = new JRadioButton("Euro");
        buttonPund = new JRadioButton("Pund");
        buttonKrona = new JRadioButton("SEK");

        buttonDollar2 = new JRadioButton("USD");
        buttonEuro2 = new JRadioButton("Euro");
        buttonPund2 = new JRadioButton("Pund");
        buttonKrona2 = new JRadioButton("SEK");

        GroupFrom.add(buttonDollar);
        GroupFrom.add(buttonEuro);
        GroupFrom.add(buttonPund);
        GroupFrom.add(buttonKrona);

        GroupTo.add(buttonDollar2);
        GroupTo.add(buttonEuro2);
        GroupTo.add(buttonPund2);
        GroupTo.add(buttonKrona2);

        left.add(labelfrom);
        left.add(buttonDollar);
        left.add(buttonEuro);
        left.add(buttonPund);
        left.add(buttonKrona);
        left.add(fieldfrom);

        middle.add(extralabel);
        middle.add(extrafield);
        middle.add(buttonOK);

        right.add(labelto);
        right.add(buttonDollar2);
        right.add(buttonEuro2);
        right.add(buttonPund2);
        right.add(buttonKrona2);
        right.add(fieldto);

        buttonOK.addActionListener(this);
        fieldfrom.addActionListener(this);
        fieldto.addActionListener(this);
        extrafield.addActionListener(this);

        buttonDollar.addActionListener(this);
        buttonDollar2.addActionListener(this);

        buttonEuro.addActionListener(this);
        buttonEuro2.addActionListener(this);

        buttonPund.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPund2.addActionListener(this);

        buttonKrona.addActionListener(this);
        buttonKrona2.addActionListener(this);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        new Adam_Markros_Valutaomvandlare();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if((fieldfrom.getText().toString()) != ""){
            currencyFrom = Integer.parseInt(fieldfrom.getText());
        }
        if((fieldto.getText().toString()) != ""){
            currencyTo = Integer.parseInt(fieldto.getText());
        }

        if((extrafield.getText().toString()) != ""){
            taljare = Integer.parseInt(extrafield.getText());
        }

        /*
        if(e.getSource() == buttonDollar){
        currencyFrom = USD;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == buttonDollar2){
        currencyTo = USD;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == buttonPund){
        currencyFrom = Pund;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == buttonPund2){
        currencyTo = Pund;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == buttonEuro){
        currencyFrom = Euro;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == buttonEuro2){
        currencyTo = Euro;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == buttonKrona){
        currencyFrom = 1;
        }
        if(e.getSource() == buttonKrona2){
        currencyTo = 1;
        }
        else{
        taljare = other;
        }
        */

        if(e.getSource() == buttonOK){

            if(buttonPund.isSelected()){
                taljare = 10;
            }
            if(buttonDollar.isSelected()){
                taljare = 6;
            }
            if(buttonEuro.isSelected()){
                taljare = 9;
            }
            if(buttonKrona.isSelected()){
                taljare = 1;
            }

            if(buttonPund2.isSelected()){
                namnare = 10;
            }
            if(buttonDollar2.isSelected()){
                namnare = 6;
            }
            if(buttonEuro2.isSelected()){
                namnare = 9;
            }
            if(buttonKrona2.isSelected()){
                namnare = 1;
            }

            currencyTo = (currencyFrom * (taljare / namnare));

            fieldto.setText(Integer.toString(currencyTo));          
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the errors:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Adam_Markros_Valutaomvandlare.actionPerformed(Adam_Markros_Valutaomvandlare.java:116)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Adam_Markros_Valutaomvandlare.actionPerformed(Adam_Markros_Valutaomvandlare.java:119)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Adam_Markros_Valutaomvandlare.actionPerformed(Adam_Markros_Valutaomvandlare.java:119)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: 1. What is the problem? 2. Please remove all unnecessary code.

Comment: It doesn't show any errors on the left side, but when I start the program and press a radio button, a red text appears that says:

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please post your error messages and all important details of your problem as an edit to your question. The information is too important to be buried in a comment.

Comment: Learn what the error messages said, they are very informative and you can always find a description/solution of your problem by Googling it. Otherwise, you will ask a lot of questions here...

Comment: What values are in `fieldfrom`, `fieldto` and `extrafield` when the action listener is called.  You are getting an error parsing a string into an int so what's in those fields will probably be revealing...

Comment: fieldfrom  = the amount you choose.
fieldto = the result.
extrafield = an extra currency.

Comment: What I meant was what values were in the text boxes.  Were they empty?  Did they contain a value that was not a number?  Check Hovercraft Full of Eels answer as he is most likely right in that your check to see if the boxes is empty is not right.

Comment: they were empty. The errors appear when I press radio buttons

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `==` or `!=` for comparing Strings since these check if one object reference is the same as another, something you're not interested in.

Use equals(...) Or in your case `isEmpty()` since these check to see if a String's contents are the same as another or if a String is empty.

```
if (!myTextField.getText().isEmpty()) {

}
```

Comment: Should I replace the " != " with " = "  ?

Comment: @user2422314  No. Again, use isEmpty()

Comment: @user2422314 please see edit to answer above.